# how to sendData on individual peer,Using multipeer connectivity framework?

Tags: objective-c

I am working with Apples Framework named Multipeer Connectivity Framework. I can `sendData` on multiple connected peer,but i want to send Data on individual peer as per my selection.

Can i do this with this framework or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that your message can carry an extra information as user id of that individual peer that you would like to send to. Apparently, all connected peer will be received the message, however, just only the one with id matches with the targeted user id in the message.

Comment: I didn't get you sir.
I just typed "HI" from textfield and now i have 3 devices connected with that device and i want to send the message on 3 and not on 1 and 2.
then how would i do this?
Please help me?

Comment: What I was saying is that 3 devices will be received your message, however, on your message, it carries the list of device Ids, which you want to deliver your message particularly. For example, the message would be converted from a dictionary right? so you can add "targeted_id" = "3". At client, you get the message, convert it to dictionary, then check whether or not the device should receive the message if matches with targeted_id, otherwise, ignore the message

Comment: sry i put my question in answer section
could you answer it there?

Comment: // It is the array of connected Peers NSArray *allPeers = _appDelegate.mcManager.session.connectedPeers; NSError *error = nil; // Method to send message [_appDelegate.mcManager.session sendData:dataToSend toPeers:allPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&error];


Now Message goes in NSData Object and where did i add this TargetID?

Comment: What is the input of your NSData Object? I think It can be everything (NSString, NSDictionary .. ). So you can create a dictionary to store values, then convert to NSData and send.

Comment: Ok sir, i have a textfield where i type the message like
"_txtMessage is UITextField" 
 NSString *message = _txtMessage.text;
    NSData *dataToSend = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
and then change it into NSData object.
Then i send it to this method
[_appDelegate.mcManager.session sendData:dataToSend toPeers:allPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&error];

Comment: Each time you receive any connection, keep their's id in an Array.NSString *userId = [array getTargetedId];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message,@"message", userId, @"userId", nil];
Convert dictionary to NSData and send. When clients receive the message, they will check if the "userId" is their's id, show message, if not, ignore.

Comment: I have done sir 
thanks for ur valuable time
thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome, hope that can help you something :)

Answer (score 0):

MC support sending data to a specific peer using the method:

```
- (BOOL)sendData:(NSData *)data toPeers:(NSArray<MCPeerID *> *)peerIDs withMode:(MCSessionSendDataMode)mode error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

As specified in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCSession/sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:

The work required on your end is to figure out which `MCPeer` should get the message.

Since the data type of `peerIDs` in the method above is of type `NSArray<MCPeerID *> *` (i.e: an `NSArray` of `MCPeer`) we understand that you can pass in not 1 but multiple peers. This means you need to find which peer is the one you want to target.

You can figure this out by iterating over the current connected peer list and select the one you like:

```
 __block MCPeer *myPeer;

    [myMCSession.connectedPeers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MCPeer *aPeer, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if(/*aPeer is equal "the peer you want*/) {
          myPeer = aPeer;
          *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

[myMCSession sendData:yourdata toPeers:@[myPeer] withMode:yourMode error:yourErrorObject];
```